# Does potential energy always equal kinetic energy?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy

When I studied physics in junior high and high school, we always took it for granted that potential energy was equal to kinetic energy. In Lagrangian terms, $T = V$at least on average. But I realized that assumption might not always be true. I have been studying the Euler-Lagrange equation and been very confused by it. But I read in *Gravity* by James Hartley that Newton's law can be expressed as the Euler-Lagrange equation.

**My Question**

If a Lagrangian satisfies the Euler-Lagrange equation, does that mean potential energy equals kinetic energy?

EDIT:

In other words, suppose I have a mass held above the surface of the earth with $PE = mgh$. That's the amount of energy that upon release gradually gets converted to kinetic energy. So therefore $PE = KE$ in that case. That's what I mean. I am saying I have always assumed the system I am considering is conservative. So when I looked at the Euler Lagrange equation, it looked trivial because had (without knowing) assumed every system satisfied it. So I am trying to see if I have the story straight this time.

Comment: You ask your question in a wrong way: when a body moves in a conservative field, the energy transforms from potential to kinetic and vice-versa. But, at a given time, the two energies are not necessarily equal. So, first, I suggest you to correct your question, and then it can be more easily examined.

Comment: The phrase "gauge transformation" may be apropos here. In the usual gauge choice two-body orbital mechanics has the property you suggest, but ...

Comment: But $T \neq V$ in general. However $dT/dt = -dV/dt$ in general.

Comment: @jld maybe that's part of why i am confused. Why can't $T=V$? I get that it might always not but are you saying it cannot be equal ever?

Comment: @StanShunpike $T=V$ under special circumstances. What's important is that $T+V=constant$ over time. There may be some points on a particle's path where $T=V$, but it certainly won't be true everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Potential energy is always measured relative to *something*, just as kinetic energy is measured *in a particular frame of reference*. That being the case, I could always make $T=V$ by choosing the reference in a certain way - but it will not generally be true.

For example, I can set $T=0$ at the top of a tower, or at ground level. Both are valid - it's really up to me. Or I can say $T=0$ at infinite distance from the earth.

And when I observe a falling object, that object will appear to be decelerating relative to a frame of reference that is moving towards the earth faster than the object.

Instead, you *can* say that

$$T + V = \mathrm{constant}$$

Because as you *lose* potential energy, you *gain* kinetic energy (assuming those are the only two forms that energy can take in your system). If you add friction, it's of course possible that the sum $T+V$ will decrease as the system warms up (unless you define thermal energy as a form of either potential or kinetic energy, which you could...)

But no, $T=V$ is not in general true.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, the (time-averaged) kinetic and potential energies, $\langle T \rangle$ and $\langle V \rangle$, are *not* the same in general.
2. E.g. the [virial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem) in Newtonian mechanics shows that 
   $$  2\langle T \rangle ~=~p\langle V \rangle ,$$
   if the potential $$V(r) \propto r^p $$ is a power law.
3. In particular, for a satellite in Newtonian gravity, $\langle V \rangle$ is minus two times $\langle T \rangle$.